# Listbox, SelectedIndexChanged doesn't fire when DataSource is set

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, datasource, selection

I use a `days` field, (which is a `BindingList<Day>`) as a `DataSource` for a `ListBox`. I have a following piece of code:

```
if (seasonId >= 0)
{
    context.DbPerform((SQLiteConnection connection) =>
    {
        foreach (var item in DBProcessor.DBSelectCustom(
                connection,
                "SELECT * FROM Days WHERE SeasonId=@seasonId;",
                (SQLiteCommand cmd) =>
        {
               var seasonIdParam = cmd.CreateParameter();
               seasonIdParam.ParameterName = "@seasonId";
               seasonIdParam.Value = seasonId;
               cmd.Parameters.Add(seasonIdParam);
         },
         DayFactory.Instance))
         {
               days.Add(item);
         }
     });
}
```

I've checked in the debugger, that after the `days.Add(item);` `ListBox`'s `SelectedIndex` changes from -1 to 0. However, no `SelectedIndexChanged` event is fired. Why? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: does DataSourceChanged fire?

Comment: @Sayse It won't fire (at least, it should not), because it fires, when DataSource property of ListBox changes and doesn't happen here.

Comment: Ah right, I was thinking that the SelectedIndexChanged doesn't fire because its not from a user input, its done programatically, just can't find evidence for this

Comment: Not managed to find any evidence but you may wish to use `listBox1.DataBindings.CollectionChanged`

Comment: I think this is by design, the `ListBox` should have some internal private variable something like `_selectedIndex` and it's changed the first time the DataBound list items count jumps from 0 to 1. The `SelectedIndexChanged` is fired only when `SelectedIndex` is changed, not the internal private variable.